# One question about quadratic residue

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

If a prime number $p$ is $1 \bmod 3$, how does one prove that there exists an integer $n$ such that $p$ divides $n^2+3$ ?

Help me, please.

Comment: This is equivalent to proving that $-3$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.

Comment: This is easy to show using [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) and its first supplement, which relates the cases where $-3$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ to cases where $p$ is a quadratic residue mod $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As remarked in the comments, show that $(\frac{-3}{p})=1$ where the brackets are the Legendre-symbol.

Because $p \equiv 1 \mod 3$, we have $(\frac{p}{3})=1$. This and the law of quad. reciprocity gives you 
$$\bigg(\frac{-3}{p}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{3}{p}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\bigg(\frac{p}{3}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$$
To compute the last term, distinguish the two cases $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and $p \not\equiv 1 \mod 4$. (This should be quite easy now.)

Comment: The "first supplement" to the law of quadatic reciprocity says:  $$ \left( \frac{-1}{p} \right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} $$

Comment: @hardmath: Ok. Using your formulation of the 1st supplement  makes my last remark redunant.